# Mysql query and reordering results

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, where-in

My SQL query is like this

```
SELECT `product_code`, `test`
FROM `table_products`
WHERE `product_code` IN ('38986', '222098', '1113426', '3645651', ...)
```

I would like the results to be ordered as in product_code order shown in query and also when there is no matching for that product_code in table, I would like to add an empty line in SQL result.

Comment: *"when there is no matching for that product_code in table, I would like to add an empty line in sql result."* why?

Comment: I assume you mean if product code `222098` does not actually exist, you want a blank row returned in the resultset! Right?

Comment: I need to export data and match to a csv file

Answer (score 1):

There (probably) is no other way except that you express the values as rows:

```
SELECT codelist.code, table_products.whatever
FROM (
    SELECT 38986 AS code, 1 AS sort UNION ALL
    SELECT 222098,        2         UNION ALL
    SELECT 1113426,       3         UNION ALL
    SELECT 3645651,       4
) AS codelist
LEFT JOIN table_products ON codelist.code = table_products.product_code
ORDER BY codelist.sort
```

The `LEFT JOIN` will give you the code number and empty right hand side row if there is no match. `ORDER BY sort` will sort the products in the desired order.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the reference product code values in another table and use right outer join

eg)

```
create table Test(id integer, title varchar(100));
create table ref(idtosee integer);//reference table
insert into ref(idtosee) values(1);
insert into ref(idtosee) values(4);
insert into Test(id, title) values(1, "Hello");
insert into Test(id, title) values(2, "sHello");


select id,title,idtosee from Test right outer join ref on id=idtosee;
```